# I can't get addEventListener to work properly

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-listener, eventhandler

I hope my question won't be too stupid, but I've just recently started to learn programming.
I'm trying to create a small counter web app where there are two buttons (minus and plus) that decrease/increase the counter by -1/+1 each time they are pressed.

There are actually two problems:

1. The counter doesn't work as expected. Every time I press on a button it increases first of +1, then +2 and so on.
2. Once I refresh the page and press on the plus button it completely ignores the conditional that disables the minus button when the counter is 0.

I noticed that if I don't nest my `eventHandlers` in the bigger function that checks first whether the counter is 0 or not the counter works exactly as expected being incremented by +1/-1.

```
let counter = document.querySelector('.num-paragraph');
const minusBtn = document.querySelector('.minus');
const plusBtn = document.querySelector('.plus');
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset-btn');
counter.textContent = 0;


plusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (counter.textContent == 0) {
        minusBtn.disabled = true;
    } else {
        minusBtn.disabled = false;
    }

    plusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        counter.textContent = Number(counter.textContent) + 1;
    });

    minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        counter.textContent = Number(counter.textContent) - 1;

    });
    resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => counter.textContent = 0);


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code. The biggest one is that you are adding event listeners inside another event listener. That's pretty much never a good idea.

What I would do is having 4 different event listeners (not nested), one for the plus button, one for the the minus, one for reset button and another one to disable the minus button:

```
plusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  counter.textContent = Number(counter.textContent) + 1;
});

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  counter.textContent = Number(counter.textContent) - 1;
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => counter.textContent = 0);

counter.addEventListener('change', function(){
  if(counter.textContent == 0){
    minusBtn.disabled = true;
  }else{
    minusBtn.disabled = false;
  }
});
```

**Note:** if your counter start at 0, you should start with the minus button disabled

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! 

Now it works. The only thing I've changed is the end, because actually "counter" is not an element that can trigger the eventListener "change". So I just made two separate 'click' event listeners for the plus and minus buttons to check for the "counter" value.

Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

I think shouldn't nest all those event listeners in `plusBtn.addEventListener`. Try to split them and make work independently. If you want to check if current counter's value is 0 to disable minus button if it's so, just move your if statement to minusBtn listener:

```
minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    counter.textContent = Number(counter.textContent) - 1;
    if (counter.textContent == 0) {
        minusBtn.disabled = true;
    } else {
        minusBtn.disabled = false;
    }
}
```